# highslide is overlapped

Tags: html

I just integrated High Slide to my wordpress site, which I found over here http://highslide.com/editor/

I am displaying a form in this high slide window, but the problem is, I have youtube video on my every post and it is overlapping the form and the window,
Check this image
[image]

I dont want this overlapping, and also when I click on the Inline HTML link(which will popup the form) I want that the background should be in dim black color

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is not with highslide, but rather with your youtube embed.

You need to add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to the object tag and `wmode="transparent"` to the embed tag. If you're using the iframe version I think it's `allowtransparency="true"` but I've never tried it with the new iframe code so I'm not sure about that last one.